# Can I compile swift 5.1 on Mojave with Xcode 11?

Tags: swift, macos-mojave, xcode11, swift5

I have Xcode 11 installed on my Mojave system (10.14.6). But Xcode doesn't let me choose Swift 5.1. What am I missing?

[[image: Swift language selection][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scPw9.png)
[[image: My Xcode version]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BWAS.png)
[[image: My macOS Version]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J8qW.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode 11 comes with Swift 5.1 compiler (even on Mojave) and you can easily check it with writing code with some Swift 5.1 feature.

```
func myFunc() -> String {
    "abc"
}
```

(SE-0255 [Implicit returns from single-expression functions](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0255-omit-return.md))

Just choose `Swift 5` and you can use Swift 5.1 features.

Comment: Thanks! I can compile the function, so you must be right. Very odd indeed!